# A Complete Video App source code for sample video app android tv

Tags: video-streaming, android-tv, android-developer-api

I want to implement video app for android smart tv.

Is any sample or free video app in android accepted format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a sample here: https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback

It provides a basic Videos by Your Company sample on Android TV using the Leanback Support Library.  Features implemented include:

- UI components like BrowseFragment, DetailFragment, SearchFragment, PlaybackOverlayFragment
- Integration with global search
- Recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Android 5.0 uses TIF (TV input framework) which allows any developer to create Live TV apps as an appk and once installed, it is automatically added to the list of input sources.

This link will guide you to build video app for android TV:

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/index.html

If you want to know more about TV Input Framework, you can follow this link:

http://source.android.com/devices/tv/index.html

Hope it helps.